# Does HttpRuntime.Cache work in Load Cluster enviornment?

Tags: caching

Does anyone have knowledge if the HttpRuntime.Cache works in load cluster enviornment? and how to implement them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by Load Cluster Environment? Do you refer to that the content of the cache should be the same on all members of the cluster?

If that is the case this can be done in two ways

- Use Sql server to serialize the cache and let all the servers point to the same sql-instance
- Use ASPNet state server, which is a windows service asp.net will talk to over tcp. Again, let all your webserver instances point to the same state server.

Another approach is not to use the HttpRuntime.Cache but implement your own cacheprovider and use technologies like memcached.